# Creating a dynamic array of pointers to a list in C

Tags: arrays, c, list, pointers, dynamic

I am new to the world of coding, doing this on hacker rank, can someone please look at my code and tell me if this is right? And how can I proceed further please?

1. Ask the user for the number of lists of integers. Store the number in a variable m.
2. Dynamically allocate an array of double pointers of length m. Each cell of the pointer will point to a list of integers (read below).
3. For each list that the user has got to enter, ask the user for the length of the list. Store the input in a variable n. Dynamically allocate an array of length n+1. Store the value of n in the first cell of the array. After that, ask the user for the integers in the list and fill the rest of the array. Assume that the list is arranged in non-decreasing order.

#include <stdio.h>

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
 
int m,n,i,j,t,**A,b;

printf("How many lists ?\n");
scanf("%d",&m);
A = (int**)malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    printf("what is length of list %d\n",(i+1));
    scanf("%d",&n);
   int *b = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {scanf("%d",&b[i]);}
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What seems to be required is not to create an array of lists, but rather a [*jagged array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) which is an array of pointers, each pointer points to the first element of an array. For this to work you need something like `A[i] = malloc(...)` instead of the variable `b`.

Comment: Understand the term "array" is used here as an analogy, there is actually no array involved. You have 2 categories of allocation to make. For `int **A;` that is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int` (a single pointer) You will allocate a block of memory to hold `m` **pointers**, assigning the return from `malloc()` to `A`. Then for each list, you will allocate storage for `n` integers and you will assign the return to your next available pointer (e.g. `A[0]`, `A[1]`, etc..You `free()` the memory in the reverse order you allocated.

Comment: And if you're "new to coding" and trying to learn programming and the C programming language, then I recommend you *don't* go to so-called "competition" sites, as they are not teaching or learning resources, unless all you want to learn are really bad habits. Get some books to read and take classes.

Comment: Also, in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)